# Equivalent of Matlabs coeff

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to find the equivalent to [Matlabs coeff](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coeff.html) function in Octave, but i'm unsure which one is correct since the description of the ones google turns up differ from the matlab page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this is in core Matlab, the page you linked says "Use only in the MuPAD Notebook Interface."

In GNU Octave you may use the symbolic octave-forge package. On a GNU/Linux system simply do:

```
pkg -forge install symbolic #only once to install
pkg load symbolic
f = sym ("10*x^10 + 5*x^5 + 2*x^2")
coeffs(f)
```

which outputs:

```
OctSymPy: Communication established.  SymPy v0.7.5.
f = (sym)

  10      5      2
  10⋅x   + 5⋅x  + 2⋅x 

octave:3> coeffs(f)
ans = (sym 1×3 matrix)

  [10  5  2]
```

Type "help @sym/coeffs" in Octave to see what the symbolic coeffs can do for you. Of course you have to install python and sympy before you can use it from symbolic.